# Xcode 9 Initial Commit so only adds source files

Tags: c++, xcode, git, version-control, xcode9-beta

I made a new C++ project, then created a repo, and Xcode 9 automatically creates an Inital Commit.
All I want to have in the initial commit is "main.cpp". (I managed to get rid of the metadata with Xcode>SourceControl>Git>IgnoredFiles by adding "*.xcodeproj".)
However, it added "._main.cpp", which is a garbage file that I don't need.

**How can I avoid adding this "._main.cpp" into git?** 
Better yet, how can I avoid Xcode creating an Initial Commit, so then I can just select the files to add myself?

Comment: Why is this tagged for C++ when your problem doesn't have anything to do the language itself?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious -- Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there wouldn't be the same issue when using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are adding files to the repository, you could add only a specific file by specifying the name of the file...

```
git add file_name
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't this via terminal? I'm hoping for a solution regarding Xcode 9.